# .htaccess - Allow acess if "REQUEST_URI" is my defined path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rules

I'm currently blocking access to the entire content of my site and allowing acess only for some IP.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Connecting-IP} !^/?198.252.206.140$
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

But i want to allow access of any file of folder /content/upload/ to everyone, and using the REQUEST_URI. I tried something like.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:REQUEST_URI} !^/?/content/upload/*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Connecting-IP} !^/?198.252.206.140$
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

But don't worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Connecting-IP} !^/?198\.252\.206\.140$
RewriteRule !^content/upload(/.*)?$ - [F,L,NC]
```

Comment: Worked, thank you. But i just used the "RewriteRule !^content/upload(/.*)?$ - [F,L,NC]", i keep the ip "clean".